# Wrong number of answers after live update

Tags: bug, answers, live-refresh

I was looking at [Center table on page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82203/center-table-on-page) when a new answer came in. At that point the question had already had had three answers, so the new one was the fourth. However, when I clicked the "1 new answer" banner to load the new answer, the caption of the answers section changed to "1 Answer" (from "3 Answers"). It should've become "4 Answers". [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eev2N.jpg) a long screen shot of the entire site.